# Getting Last number in array (input and output) C#

Tags: c#, input, android-activity

Hi i'm new in c# programming i'm doing an activity that Will Enter How many inputs and it will view the inserted numbers . Now i only have one problem how can i view only the last inserted number here's my code:

```
     Console.Write("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[num1];
        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
            Console.Write("Input Value #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.Write("The Numbers inserted are: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++) {
            Console.Write(" " + arr[x]);
        }
        Console.Write("The Last Number Inserted is: ");
        (???)

  Sample Output:
  Enter How Many Inputs: 3
  Value #1: 80
  Value #2: 83
  Value #3: 50
  The Numbers inserted are: 80 83 50
  The Last Number inserted is: 50
```

I don't have idea what looping will i use to view the last inserted number.Thank you!

Comment: `arr[arr.length-1]` doesn't suffice?

Comment: @codingbiz I think the OP is fairly new to programming so would be better if we can just help him.Your comment is not useful I feel.

Comment: @freebird only possible 15 minutes after posting the question.

Comment: @freebird Some basic important lessons must have been skipped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr[arr.length-1]
```

Or

```
arr[num1-1]
```

Comment: Are you sure OP's not seeking for something more... beautiful? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak What more ... beautiful?

Comment: sir how about The First Number inserted is : ?

Comment: @Jay Jan's comment is what you need.

Comment: Thanks sir @freebird . Thumbs up for you.!

Answer (score 2):

Last element of array can be processed by

```
arrayname[totalsize-1]
```

Because array is stared with `0th` index , that's why `[totalsize-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `arr.Last()`

> `public static TSource Last<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source)`
>
> Member of System.Linq.Enumerable

This will give you the last element of sequence.